# How i can store 64 byte data into flash faster as 1 ms?

Tags: microcontroller, flash, dma, lpc1768

I have one problem with store data into flash on my uC LPC1759. I need to save 64 byte data into flash, but when i use IAP-Interface, it takes more than 1 second. Is there a way to make it faster than 1 ms ? It is possible use DMA for copy data from RAM to Flash? Or write data to flash less than 256 Byte ( UM10360 - minimum size - 256 Byte).

Comment: My guess is that the 1 second is mainly the erase time? You might be able to *write* much faster (but I doubt you could reach 1 ms) when the block is already erased. But the real solution is probably to use external eeprom.

Comment: Consider FRAM, or even battery-backed SRAM possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

The flash programming time (for the 256 byte block) is 1 *milli*second. See chapter 12.1 "Flash memory" in the datasheet. And no, you cannot write to flash any faster.

Comment: In UM10360 for LPC175x?

Comment: No, the "Product datasheet" for [LPC1759](http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC1759_58_56_54_52_51.pdf)

Comment: Maybe it works for programm flash from bootloader, but in IAP this does not work

Comment: I used those IAP functions myself, they **work**. The block must be erased first, of course. Erase works only for complete 4k/64kB sectors.